# Limitations of an agent in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

We recently have added 100s of pages of training phrases for intents at least get more accuracy in the intent responses. which ironically didn't help too much but rather caused the agent to start behaving incorrectly.
Adding a lot of training phrases was encourage by the Dialogflow team but it seems there is still a limit for that.

I am trying to restore the agent in dialogflow that unzips to around 70mb now but I am getting an error saying:
Unzipped file size is too big! We allow maximum 50 MBs dialogflow.

It seems that we push the system again to the limit but we didn't know it will actually break everything.

Is there a way to remove those limitation for our specific agent? or is there a way for us to know upfront all the limitations that seems to be hidden.

Comment: Can you perhaps post details of the error encountered?  If there are specific tags, or tokens or a recipe to recreate, it might ring a bell.  If you have a Dialogflow definition that was large and "good" and you exported it and now you can't re-import it, that smells like a defect to me.

Comment: @Kolban that is exactly the error that i added. "Unzipped file size is too big! We allow maximum 50 MBs dialogflow."

Comment: Was this message logged to the screen?  Is there more of a context as to where one sees the message?  Is there a REST or other API that attempts to do the same thing that might have a documented caveat or restriction?  Maybe try this API and see what happens ... https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent/import